# How to edit Qt4 source and make changes apply

Tags: source, c++, qt, qt4

Basically, I have a change to be done in

```
/usr/src/qt/src/src/gui/kernel/qclipboard_x11.cpp
```

There is a 10s timeout that causes apps to hang on shutdown (search the file for the word "reasonable"). Not very reasonable, in fact.

For illustration, this is what I want to mitigate - I can't open another instance of Okular until the 10 seconds timeout ends.

```
<terminal>

okular(9173) Okular::Utils::realDpiY: Pix: 1080 MM: 285
okular(9173) Okular::Utils::realDpiX: Pix: 1920 MM: 508
okular(9173) Okular::DocumentPrivate::openDocumentInternal: Output DPI: QSizeF(96, 96.2526)
...
(window is closed)
...
(10 seconds later)
...
QClipboard: Unable to receive an event from the clipboard manager in a reasonable time
```

Here I should be able to fix it:

```
<file qtclipboard_x11.cpp>

XEvent event;
// waiting until the clipboard manager fetches the content.
if (!X11->clipboardWaitForEvent(ownerId, SelectionNotify, &event, /*HERE->*/ 10000, true)) {
    qWarning("QClipboard: Unable to receive an event from the "
             "clipboard manager in a reasonable time");
}
```

I've changed this to 3 seconds, which should be much better.

How to make the changes apply?

Is there some makefile to run to rebuild Qt from these sources, or am I doing it completely wrong? I assume there's some qt library object file that needs to be rebuilt, but I can't find a way to do it.

Thanks.

btw. it's Arch install with Xfce, if it's relevant in any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply your changes you need to rebuild this package. You can read description on [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR#Acquire_build_files).

Comment: That's not a good answer at all, the package is not even from AUR.

Comment: @MightyPork See [ABS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ABS) for packages from official repositories.

Comment: The bug persists and I finally got off my lazy ass to fix it. Rebuilding Qt4 as we speak. My laptop doesn't like it xD